# How to get the id when the character matches

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I will get a input form df1 in that if the name is matches from df i need to get the respective id ex(health means 2) can anyone help me on this how to capture that id

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), B = c('agri','health','edu','energy'))
    
df1 <- data.frame(name = c('agri','health','edu','energy'))
```

Comment: You can use `match` i.e `df$id[match('health', df$B)]` ? Is that what you need?

Comment: no , i will get only one input so need to get specific id of name ex if i get input as agri then i need to get the output  id 1 @RonakShah

Comment: I think that is what my comment does. Instead of `'health'` you replace with the name that you get.

Comment: actually dont know why it was showing na in my application is there any other way to acheive this

Comment: What do you mean with "any other way to achieve this"? Don't the provided solutions here work? If they don't then please explain your problem as well as your desired output a bit better.

Comment: i changed little bit on my application now the code is works thanks @RonakShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in all matches:

```
df$id[match(df1$name, df$B)]
```

Maybe you want to add the respective id to your `df1`data?

Then you can do:

```
df1$new_id <- df$id[match(df1$name, df$B)]
```

which gives:

```
    name new_id
1   agri      1
2 health      2
3    edu      3
4 energy      4
```

Comment: the name which is in df1 it should match the df then i need the respective id ex in df1 i select agri then it should give the respective id of 1 which is in df

Comment: Similar to what @Ronak Shah said in his comment above, this is exactly what the function does. Ronak Shah's solution lets you decide which name you want to match, whereas my solution gives you all matches, i.e. it tells you which id belongs to "agri", which one to "health" and so on.